# Unable to locate element selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to fill in a form using this code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
browser = webdriver.Chrome( chrome_options=chrome_options)
browser.get('https://www.vwe.nl/Autobedrijf/In-en-verkoop/bpm-calculator- 
doorverkoop')

time.sleep(5)

#browser.switch_to_frame(browser.find_element_by_id("_hjRemoteVarsFrame"))  

kenteken = browser.find_element_by_id('InputControl_txtKenteken')
kenteken.send_keys('simple text')
```

I tried to see if there is an iframe but it didn't work.

[image: html body of the element]

But it drops an error :  Unable to locate element

Comment: is iframe on DOM?

Comment: Have you checked that the element is actually present? Maybe the 5sec sleep is not enough.
Does it find your element when you search for it using this css selector in the Inspect Code window (when you use ctrl+f inside the window you're showing)?

Comment: I suggest verify context by something like iframe = self.finding_element(By.TAG_NAME, "iframe") and then switch to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your element inside `iframe`, you need switch it first.

This is the `iframe` locator: `By.CLASS_NAME -> iframe_bpm`.

You can use combination `WebDriverWait` and `expected_conditions` then utilize `frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it` method to switch.

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome( chrome_options=chrome_options)
browser.get('https://www.vwe.nl/Autobedrijf/In-en-verkoop/bpm-calculator-doorverkoop')
browser.maximize_window()
WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CLASS_NAME, 'iframe_bpm')))

kenteken = browser.find_element_by_id('InputControl_txtKenteken')
kenteken.send_keys('simple text')
```

Following import:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an iframe you need to switch it first.Use WebDriverWait.

```
driver.get("https://www.vwe.nl/Autobedrijf/In-en-verkoop/bpm-calculator-doorverkoop")
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'.iframe_bpm')))
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,"InputControl_txtKenteken"))).send_keys('text')
```

use following imports.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
```